# How do I get the true negatives from y_true and y_pred?

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, keras

Is it possible to get **true negative** from `y_true` and `y_pred` tensors in Keras?

I know we can get true positives from the following code:

```
true_positive = K.sum(y_true*y_pred)
```

How to do the same for the true negative?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's an example of how you can extract the `True Positive` and the `True Negative` values of your `confusion matrix`:

```
def confusion(y_true, y_pred):
    y_pred_pos = K.round(K.clip(y_pred, 0, 1))
    y_pred_neg = 1 - y_pred_pos
    y_pos = K.round(K.clip(y_true, 0, 1))
    y_neg = 1 - y_pos
    tp = K.sum(y_pos * y_pred_pos) / K.sum(y_pos)
    tn = K.sum(y_neg * y_pred_neg) / K.sum(y_neg)
    return {'true_pos': tp, 'true_neg': tn}
```

In case you are facing some `NaN` values in your output, try adding an epsilon to the denominators which will solve your problem.

[Answer came from this link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/keras-users/eyUep1I1fR4).

Hope it helped you.